# Using Mongoose and Luxon to try and display date of event, but I'm getting the day before

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, luxon

I am using Mongoose and Luxon to display a date, selected by the user from a form. But the date is console.logging one date, but displaying on the page as the day before.

This is my model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { DateTime, Settings } = require("luxon");

// Configure time zone
console.log(Settings);

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let AccomplishmentSchema = new Schema({
  dateInput: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  textInput: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

AccomplishmentSchema.virtual("dateInput_formatted").get(function () {
  return DateTime.fromJSDate(this.dateInput).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_FULL); // format 'YYYY-MM-DD
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Accomplishment", AccomplishmentSchema);
```

And this is my console log vs what is showing up on the page

```
 dateInput: 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
 textInput: 'etst',
```

December 31, 2022
etst

I can only assume this has to do with some kind of time conversion, but I've tried changing the time zone, and the settings, although I could've read the docs wrong. I cannot find a way to fix this issue.

Comment: Timezones are hard.  Midnight UTC(Z) will be the day before in any timezone west of the prime meridian.

Comment: Have you worked with Luxon? I just started playing around with it because it’s on the mdn express docs. 

Going through their docs it seems like it defaults to the system’s timezone, but I cannot figure out why what’s being displayed in the DOM would be diff than what the console log would show

Comment: The console log is showing the datetime as midnight 1 Jan _in UTC_.  `toLocaleString` will convert that to the configured timezone of the system.  If that timezone is anything in the americas, it will correctly show the date as 31 Dec

Comment: Oh interesting. I just assumed it would take the input as whatever timezone my browser is in. Any advice on how to get the inputted data to be in the correct timezone?

Comment: That would depend on the `dateInput`.  You might play around with the options object https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromjsdate and see if there is a way to sync that to the browser's default tz

Comment: Thank you for your time and insights! I appreciate you responding and helping me see this problem from a diff angle. I’m going to dive back into it and figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with JS `Date`, the most important thing to understand is that `Date` doesn't store or know about a time zone. It simply stores the number of milliseconds since midnight on Jan 1, 1970 (aka [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing))) in the UTC time zone.  Then, when you call `Date` methods, the results are calculated for the current user's time zone (for methods like `getMinutes()`) or UTC (for methods like `getUTCMinutes()`).  But the underlying data inside the `Date` is just a timezone-less number of milliseconds.

With that in mind, let's look at a simple example: `new Date(0)`, which is equivalent to `new Date('1970-01-01T00:00Z')`.

If your computer's time zone set to the `Europe/Paris` time zone, then when you call `new Date(0).toLocaleDateString('en-US')` then you'll get a result of `'1/1/1970'`. But if you change your computer's time zone to `America/Los_Angeles` and run the same code, you'll get a result of `'12/31/1969'`.

This happens because the `Date`'s stored value corresponds to midnight on  Jan 1, 1970 in the UTC time zone. In Paris that instant was 1:00AM on Jan 1, 1970, while in California it was 4:00PM on December 31, 1969.  The same exact `Date` will print a different date depending on the time zone that's active at the time that date is printed.

Where this becomes particularly problematic is in cases where you're trying to express a date without a time. For example, assume you store a `Date` value of `2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` in MongoDB.

When you display that `Date` in a date picker in a browser in California, the date shown will be Dec 31, 2022, because California is 8 hours ahead of UTC.

One way to solve this problem is to tell `Date` that the date you're using is a UTC date. Like this:

```js
utcDateStoredInMongoDB = new Date ('2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
// Get the year, month, and day in that Date, from the perspective
// of the UTC time zone.
year = utcDateStoredInMongoDB.getUTCFullYear();
month = utcDateStoredInMongoDB.getUTCMonth();
day = utcDateStoredInMongoDB.getUTCDate();
// Use that year, month, day to initialize a new Date in
// the user's time zone.
dateForDatePicker = new Date(year, month, day);
// Use that for your date picker.
dateForDatePicker.toLocaleDateString();
// => '1/1/2023'

// To go in the other direction, pull out the year/month/day
// in the current time zone, and turn that into a UTC date.
dateReturnedByDatePicker = new Date(2023, 02, 15);
year = dateReturnedByDatePicker.getFullYear();
month = dateReturnedByDatePicker.getMonth();
day = dateReturnedByDatePicker.getDate();
dateToStoreInMongoDB = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day));
dateToStoreInMongoDB.toISOString();
// => '2023-03-15T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Note that this all will get a lot easier in a year or so when the new JavaScript built-in date/time API, called [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) starts shipping in browsers and Node.js. With Temporal, these kinds of problems are much easier because there's a dedicated API, [`Temporal.PlainDate`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindate.html) for dealing with date-only values.

Comment: I used your code utcDateStoredInMongoDB ... inside of my virtual and the Date issue seems to be fixed!

Is this the correct implementation of the code? I am new to working with virtuals, but it's the only place that I could think of for this code to be.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem, but if the code works for you and you understand why it works, then it should be good for you.

Answer (score 2):

Luxon is working as intended and the display is correct. What is wrong is the data in your MongoDB.

Most libraries consider current time zone when you parse a date. I live in Switzerland.

```
const moment = require("moment");
console.log( moment('2023-01-01').toDate() )
> 2022-12-31T23:00:00.000Z

const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
console.log( DateTime.fromISO('2023-01-01').toJSDate() )
> 2022-12-31T23:00:00.000Z

const dayjs = require('dayjs')
console.log( dayjs('2023-01-01').toDate() )
> 2022-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

However, the native JavaScript `new Date()` constructor does not!

```
console.log( new Date('2023-01-01') )
> 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Maybe this behavior depends on your environment and scripting engine, I don't know.

You should also use Luxon when you parse the input data - don't forget to use `.toJSDate()` to convert the DateTime object back to Javascript native `Date` object.

Luxon uses the [system time zone](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/zones?id=system-zone-by-default) by default. You can change it:

```
const { DateTime, Settings } = require("luxon");
Settings.defaultZone = 'America/New_York';
```

If you don't care about the time, you can also use [startOf('day')](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof)

```
Settings.defaultZone = 'America/New_York';
DateTime.now().startOf('day').toJSDate()
> 2023-01-13T05:00:00.000Z

DateTime.now().startOf('day').toISO()
> '2023-01-13T00:00:00.000-05:00'
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! I appreciate your explanation!